# How to get uncleaned CharField data from a form in a django formset?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I would like to get a charField from a form in a django formset without cleaning the data first. Cleaning the data removes the white space and for a particular Charfield I would like to keep the exact input.

I have a form inside a formset and get most of the data fields by

```
for form in formset:
    cd = form.cleaned_data
    name = cd.get('name')
```

however I do not want to get the CharField by cleaning the data for a particular field.
I was attempting to get the field like this

```
for form in formset:
    name = form['name_of_field']
```

but it does not work

Answer (score 0):

To access the field from a form within a formset without calling cleaned_data, you need to add `.value()` like this:

```
for form in formset:
    name = form['name_of_field'].value()
```